# Динамический обработчик для таймера в консольном приложении

Tags: c#, таймер, консоль

**Вот, что есть:**

```
    public System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke Handler()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("123");
            return System.ComponentModel.ISynchronizeInvoke;
        }

        public Game()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.SynchronizingObject = Handler();
        }
```

**А скажите, пожалуйста, как надо... Спасибо.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании указать делегат для сообщения Elapsed

```
aTimer.Elapsed += (OnTimedEvent);
```

В том же классе описать этот делегат

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

А таймеры вообще работают в консольном приложении? Для них вроде нужен цикл с обработкой сообщений.

Comment: Работают же.

Comment: для подобных однострочных обработчиков можно использовать 

    aTimer.Elapsed += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);

Comment: @Spectre, лямбда функции...спасибо)